# How to cover the entire background when rotating an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, image-rotation

I’m trying to rotate a an ImageView as a background. I set the ratio of the ImageView, but that’s not enough since the ImageView which is red in the picture below when rotating.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/crQa1.jpg

How can I fix so that the red ImageView covers the entire background the entire rotation?

Under is the code I currently have:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
android:duration="70000"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:startOffset="0"
android:toDegrees="360" />
```

And:

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageBackground"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="40dip"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:scaleType="center"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/rotatingbackground" />
```

Comment: remove this: `android:layout_margin="40dip"` and try

Comment: @UmangBurman Still the same result

Comment: if image covers entire background, how do you know it rotating. we always see red background occupied whole screen.

Comment: @navylover when the app starts the red covers the entire background, but after the rotation has started the white behind the Image appears in each corner as shown in the picture. The red color is just an example. I actually rotate another picture.

Comment: yes, but you don't want to see the white corner, do you? may be use an image big enough could solve

Comment: @navylover Exactly so I need to set the height of the ImageView equal to "wrap_content * 1.4" or something like that so that the image view covers the corners when it's rotating. The picture is big enough I just need a way to set the height of the ImageView bigger than the actual screen size.